# Unable to copy file from SFTP in Azure Data Factory when using wildcard(*) in the filename

Tags: azure, ftp, sftp, azure-data-factory

I am unable to copy csv files from an SFTP connection to blob storage when using the wildcard(*) in the filename.

More specifically, I receive csv files in the SFTP on a daily basis, and they are of the format: "ddMMyyyyxxxxxx.csv", where "xxxxxx" is the timestamp. More concretely, my csv file for the 13th of March is: "13032019083647.csv", while for the 14th of March: "14032019083556.csv". Obviously, the timestamp is different for every day, thus I want to copy the file independently of whatever strings exists between the date and the the file extenstion.

In the "File" subfield of the "File path" of the "Connection" tab of my subset, I give as input: "13032019*.csv", as instructed by the help icon next to the field:

[image: File name or file filter]

When I do so, my Debug run fails with:

> {"errorCode": "2200", "message":
>   "ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidCopyBehaviorBlobNameNotAllowedWithPreserveOrFlattenHierarchy,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot
>   adopt copy behavior PreserveHierarchy when copying from folder to a
>   single file.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary}

I receive a similar error no matter which type of copy behaviour I choose. I have also tried experimenting with the fileFilter parameter (even though ADF warns that the same behaviour can be achieved with the fileName option), but I still end up getting the same error.

For further clarification, I am attaching the Code segment that ADF produces for this configuration:

[image: Code segment with failing fileName]

I should also mention, that when using the full fileName in the corresponding field, namely the value: "13032019083647.csv", copying works normally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was the following: I kept the same regex for the input file, but I defined as "Copy behaviour: Merge Files". Since as mentioned, there is only 1 file that satisfies the regex condition, only 1 file was created as output. I am aware that this is a sort of "dirty" solution, but it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

My guess it might get two files with wildcard operation.
In such cases we need to use metadata activity, filter activity and for-each activity to copy these files.

1.Metadata activity : Use data-set in these activity to point the particular location of the files and pass the child Items as the parameter.

2.Filter activity : Use filter to filter the files based on your needs.

3.For-each activity : In the For-each activity get Items from the previous activity and add copy activity inside the for-each.
In copy activity the source data set should be @item().name.

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Interestingly, when using the wildcard filtering, azure data factory automatically assumes that it reads in a folder (and not a file), even though there is only 1 file that satisfies the condition... Thus, that is the reason that it was failing with the given error. @Yunvraj I will try your approach and let you know if it works properly.

Comment: @loannis. That works or not. let us know if you have tried any other logic to achieve this.

Comment: posted my answer